# C# regular expression for 2018-09-24 22:42:02.071042000

Tags: c#, regex, regular-language

Goal: need to extract the string "2018-09-24 22:42:02" from the string below:

```
-rw-rw-rw- 1 rats 38K 2018-09-24 22:42:02.071042000 +0000 /prod/data/automation_sent/20180924/11/20180924_1100600.sps
```

I tried the following reg expressions but they dont seem to work with my string above:

An unescaped delimiter must be escaped with a backslash ():

```
\d{4}(?:/\d{1,2}){2}
```

changed to

```
\d{4}(?:\/\d{1,2}){2}
```

and got the wrong string

```
\d{4}[- /.]([1-9]|0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.]([1-9]|0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])
```

no matches:

```
\d{4}$|^\d{4}-((0?\d)|(1[012]))-(((0?|[12])\d)|3[01])
```

not sure what I am missing... any help is welcomed,

Thank you

Comment: Parse it as a DateTime instead and you're done...

Comment: Use `string.Join(" ", s.Split().Skip(4).Take(2)).Split('.')[0]`

Comment: @JeffMercado `DateTime.Parse("-rw-rw-rw- 1 rats 38K 2018-09-24 22:42:02.071042000 +0000 /prod/data/automation_sent/20180924/11/20180924_1100600.sps");` ?

Comment: Please post the actual c# code. Using double backslashes is probably one way to solve your issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about this?

```
        string input = @"-rw-rw-rw- 1 rats 38K 2018-09-24 22:42:02.071042000 +0000 /prod/data/automation_sent/20180";
        string regex = @"\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}";

        var match = Regex.Match(input, regex);
```

Comment: Close, but it won't match the sub-second values at the end of the expected match.

Comment: Exactly what I needed it. I can do without the miliseconds. TryParseExact could not take fffffffff anyways, it just accepts fff from what I checked.
Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

https://www.regextester.com/97766 has a good matcher for ISO dates. You can leverage this regex but remove the `^` and `&` and replace the T with a white space.

The resulting regex is `(-?(?:[1-9][0-9]*)?[0-9]{4})-(1[0-2]|0[1-9])-(3[01]|0[1-9]|[12][0-9]) (2[0-3]|[01][0-9]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])(.[0-9]+)?(Z)?`